# How to make lists in a TabView scroll with the main ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So basically I have a view whose structure looks like this:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        VStack {...}
        TabView {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(1...300, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("\(text) \(index)")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
                        .background(backgroundColor)
                }
            }
            // Other placeholder tabs
        }
    }
}
```

**The issue** with this is that the main `ScrollView` and the `ScrollView` within the tabview are separate and therefore scroll independent of one another. **What I'd ultimately like to achieve is** the profile layout like TikTok where the main `ScrollView` and the content of the `TabView` scroll together however I cannot figure out how because I'm new to SwiftUI.

**Edit:**

As requested, here is the video of what I am trying to achieve. Basically the entire page is one `ScrollView` but theres also a `ScrollView` within the `TabView` and they scroll together until the `Tabs` are at the top of the page when the inner `ScrollView` takes control:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest attaching a video of the profile layout in TikTok. For people who don't haver the app :)

Comment: @Ori I have added the example

Comment: Probably you have to use the geometry reader to read out the desired values and code the behavior you want by yourself.

Comment: @Felix yes I have been trying to do so for these couple days. I'm just not sure how a functionality so widely used isn't easier to implement.

Comment: @camelCaseIsGoodPractice, have you managed to solve it? If yes, could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @PavelMalinnikov no I didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for adding the video :)

What you are looking for is called **Sticky header**

> Sticky headers (or persistent headers) are a common pattern for
> keeping the header of a website or app in the same place on the screen
> while the user scrolls down the page. A version of this pattern is the
> partially sticky header, which (re)appears at the top of the page as
> soon as the user starts scrolling up.

I have found two tutorials that I believe will help you:

[SwiftUI Animated Sticky Header](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATi5EnY5IYE) & [Instagram Profile Sticky Header](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XwWtWG3ZP0)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have watched both videos before and they miss one crucial part - the tabs. I already have the sticky headers in place but my view has tabs which have a scrollable body but TabView has a set height and therefore I need to add ScrollView inside it. Have two separate scroll views means they don’t scroll together. That’s my issue at the moment.

Comment: Did you find out the solution, getting the same issue?